# What's the structure behind Apple version numbers / build numbers?

Tags: software, build-version

macOS Sierra 10.12.3 is `16D32`, but the SDK is `16C58` according to my Xcode.

iOS 10.3 beta is `14E5239e`.

Xcode 8.2 is `8C38`.

You know how they look, and they are shared among all Apple software.

But how are they made up? What's the logic behind? I can barely guess that "sometimes", the first number is the "major" version, eg. for Xcode, but that's not always true, eg. for iOS.

And what's the middle letter about?

The last number surely is a sequential build number, with minor revisions having a lowercase letter appended (take iOS 10.3 beta).

Do they all start at `1A1` internally, then move on build after build?

What is the greater scheme at play here?

Comment: To be honest, I asked this to see if I could replicate "their" versioning scheme in our own software and CI environment. It's not out of pure curiosity. Close if you will, I understand.

Comment: @fsb I encourage you to look at the answers provided for why this question is not off-topic.

Comment: @grgarside I disagree and still think it's off-topic, however, I've removed my comments and close vote.

Comment: My use of the term "rationale" was maybe a little confusing, too. Twenty years practicing English and I'm still sometimes lost on words :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Paul Suh](https://www.linkedin.com/in/pasuh/) (formerly a consulting engineer and training developer at Apple, [wrote the following](http://blog.joemoreno.com/2007/11/apple-software-build-numbers.html) (published on Joe Moreno's blog):

> For instance, Mac OS X 10.4.10 Intel is build 8R2232. Mac OS X Server
>   10.4.11 Universal is 8S2169. These numbers have the following rough meanings:
>
> 8 - This is the major version number of the software package. 10.5 =
>   9, 10.4 = 8, ... 10.0 = 4. Prior to that was NextStep 3.3, from which
>   we get the 3 series.
>
> R - This is the minor version number. It is always incremented for
>   system updates (i.e. 10.4.10 to 10.4.11 is always a letter jump), but
>   may be incremented as well for hardware-specific builds. R is the 18th
>   letter, but only the 10th update to Tiger. The other 8 letter bumps
>   were for hardware support for new releases. Security updates generally
>   don't merit a letter bump.
>
> 2232 - This is the sequential build number within the minor version.
>   If it is a four-digit number, the first digit indicates a specific
>   platform. In this case, 2 indicates that it is for Intel. A
>   three-digit or shorter number indicates a unified build for all
>   architectures. The remaining digits are the sequential build number.
>   In this case, the R train had 232 builds before release, the first one
>   being build 8R2001. Although the builds are roughly daily, you can't
>   really go by that number. In the early stages builds may only happen
>   once every two or three days; towards the end they may occur two or
>   three times a day. The build trains of successive releases may overlap
>   to a certain extent, based on what Apple Engineering sees as the
>   priority vs. risk of various changes to the code. The earliest builds
>   of 10.4.11 almost certainly overlapped with the last builds of
>   10.4.10. The builds of Leopard definitely overlapped with builds of Tiger updates, going back to almost all the way to the day after Tiger
>   was released.
>
> Note that different software packages have totally different build
>   numbers, so you can't compare the build numbers to each other in a
>   meaningful way. The exception is that Mac OS X and Mac OS X Server
>   share the same build numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In an [article](https://www.macrumors.com/2013/06/06/os-x-10-9-build-number-suggests-extensive-internal-development/) MacRumors refers to *Apple's build number scheme*. Although not an offical resource it does indicate there is a certain logic behind the numbering.

> According to Apple's build number scheme, "13" refers to OS X 10.9,
>   "A" refers to the 10.9.0 version, and "451" is part of a sequential
>   numbering of compiled builds.